# Codeigniter-Pagination: Why is my datatable displaying more than 5 entries?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

```
    public function search($offset = 0)
{

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $per_page = 5;
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results('ghost_projects');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'project/search';
    $config['total_rows'] = $count;
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $config['first_url'] = '1';
    $config['cur_page'] = '1';
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->data['projects'] = $this->addproject_m->ongoingprojects($per_page, $offset);     
    $this->data['subview'] = 'project/search';
    $this->load->view('_layout_main_1', $this->data);
```

This is the code in my controller, I have specified the required entries per page yet it shows me 10 entries, can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

The create links function I have added in the view, Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: doesn't that fetch from active record db? I am sorry but i thought count_all_results was an inbuilt function?

Comment: echo `$count = $this->db->count_all_results('ghost_projects');` and check the value of it

Comment: The value of it is 10. But why isn't it taking `$per_page` into consideration? I am sorry but I am in training and unaware of these issues.

Comment: okk just comment this two line and check `$config['first_url'] = '1';
    $config['cur_page'] = '1';`

Comment: i have commented them both, still no change. `public function count_all_results($table = '')
 {
  if ($table != '')
  {
   $this->_track_aliases($table);
   $this->from($table);
  }

  $sql = $this->_compile_select($this->_count_string . $this->_protect_identifiers('numrows'));

  $query = $this->query($sql);
  $this->_reset_select();

  if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
  {
   return 0;
  }

  $row = $query->row();
  return (int) $row->numrows;
 }` 
This is the code in DB_active_rec.php

Comment: I remember trying to use CI pagination, and in my opinion the doc page isnt enough to get through it. Here's a complete example I suggest you to read : http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/
Please read the 1st comment which fixes a bug of this tuto.